# joomla mootools upgrade crashes

Tags: joomla, mootools1.2

I have a problem I'm trying to solve for a few days now.
We enabled the mootools 1.2 plugin in joomla 1.5 so we can use some libraries designed for mootools 1.2 .
It worked great, everything was working and we could continue our work.
Since the last time the script worked, we did some minor changes, adding squeezebox compatibility to the front end, included the cufon script so the page would look better,...
There were really only minor changes.
The next time I looked mootools crashed.
Internet explorer is throwing errors like :

Message: 'className' is null or not an object
Line: 335
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: /plugins/system/mtupgrade/mootools.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 47606
Code: 0
URI: /plugins/system/mtupgrade/mootools.js

Message: Number expected
Line: 1
Char: 2585
Code: 0
URI: /plugins/system/mtupgrade/mootools.js

And this errors are thrown on simple tasks like :
$('element').className='something';

The code wasn't changed and it worked perfectly before.

Can somebody push me into the right direction?
I already tried to undo the changes we made, didn't work.

Comment: It seems that I have made an error during development. Maybe this errors were before, but I noticed it only cause I opened the project in internet explorer. Still this errors are cause of mootools, does anyone know yhat could be the reason? I would be thankfull for every answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Seems that mootools was loaded 2 times. The second time it was loaded in the new template and therefore the errors.